# SQL left join returns all the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, `table1` that has 129 rows. I'd like to join another table `table2` with 429 rows to it, and end up with only 129 rows.

So far, I've tried:

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id;
```

But I always end up with 429 rows.

I'm clearly missing something here. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Do you need an Inner Join?

Comment: Do all rows in `table2` have an `id` that matches a row in `table1`?

Comment: Yes, and then some.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: `with cte as (select distinct (Id) from table2) Select * from table1 left join cte on cte.id = table1.id`

Comment: " table2 has some multiples of table1's ids".  A left join can multiply rows on equal matching ON conditions.  This commonly occurs if you don't join on a primary key or distinct column.  If the tableA ids are distinct, and you match to tableB ids which are multiples of id's contained in tableA- then you will multiply rows in tableA by the LEFT JOIN and will get the exact number of rows in tableB.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore were u able solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Inner join is what you might need

```
select table1.*
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately even the inner join still returns all 429 results instead of the 129 results.

Comment: Could this be if table2 contains multiple instances of table1.id?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I updated the query, Can u try the updated query?

Comment: I did, it returned all the records from table2. table2 has some multiples of table1's ids. I think I'm inching towards a solution.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore it shouldn't because we are using `table.*` in the `select` clause

Answer (score 1):

This image always helps me when constructing SQL joins.  It's usually the top result when googling "sql joins"

[image]

Comment: I think the query you want is:  `LEFT JOIN TableB .. WHERE B.Key IS NULL`